# Translate XAMPP errors to spanish

Tags: php, xampp

I download the spanish version of xampp to work with. The phpmyadmin modules and info are working right but when i write some code and apache shows me the errors, those errors are still in english.

Is there a way to change or translate this errors to spanish? Where i must look at?

Answer (score 0):

For best results, I would recommend that you copy and paste the error into Google and then translate the resulting page. Most content regarding the errors will be on english sites. If you translate first you might not get any results. So search first, translate the results.

Comment: That doesnt help because im NOT the one with the problem. I need to translate by the program itselft because i have a blind students who is learning programming, but he is not quite good at english. The jaws software talks to fast for understand what it is saying. @Citizen

Comment: @AlejandroMaliachiQuintana I think you would be better off looking into slowing down Jaws then. I'm not aware of any program that translates XAMPP errors. You could write your own script that checks for new errors by checking the log and leverage google translate to update the language before sending it to your auditory assistance program. That's the only thing I can think of.